# What does "(which see)" mean in various Emacs help docstrings?

Tags: help, documentation

In various Emacs docstrings the text include the *"(which see)"* mention right after a reference to a variable as shown in the second paragraph of the example below, taken from the `emacs-lock` docstring.  What does this mean?  Is it supposed to be rendered in a special way?

> Emacs-Lock minor mode (indicator Locked:all):
> Toggle Emacs Lock mode in the current buffer.
> If called with a plain prefix argument, ask for the locking mode
> to be used.

> Initially, if the user does not pass an explicit locking mode, it
> defaults to ‘emacs-lock-default-locking-mode’ (which see);
> afterwards, the locking mode most recently set on the buffer is
> used instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What does this mean?

It's a suggestion from the documentation author to read the documentation of the thing it's referencing (ie. `emacs-lock-default-locking-mode`)

> Is it supposed to be rendered in a special way?

"(which see)" itself? No. The thing being referenced? Yes.

In my Emacs, in "gui mode" (`emacs -q`) we get:
[image: screenshot of an Emacs window displaying help for "emacs-lock-mode"]

The blue underlined words are navigable links. You can click on them with your mouse, or cycle through them with the <kbd>TAB</kbd> and "click them" with the <kbd>Enter</kbd>/<kbd>Return</kbd>.

In my Emacs, in "terminal mode" (`emacs -q -nw`) we get:

[image: screenshot of an Emacs window in terminal mode displaying the help for "emacs-lock-mode"]

You'll notice the same blue, underlined links. Obviously you can't navigate them with your mouse, but you can still use <kbd>TAB</kbd> and <kbd>Enter</kbd>. For more help on navigating `*Help*` buffers, hit <kbd>h</kbd> while in a `*Help*` buffer.

Comment: You can navigate the links with your mouse if your terminal emulator is configured correctly.

Comment: You might need to activate xterm-mouse-mode to navigate with your mouse.

Comment: Given the fact that the preceding term is already rendered as a hyperlink, I would argue that `(which see)` is superfluous and, I don't know, is the word "precious" or is it "contrived"? A bit of both.